# Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found when running compilation - Magento 2

Tags: php, phpunit, magento2, magento2.2

I have problem in the magento 2.2.3 compilation.
when I run the compile command

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Its output this

Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 58.0 MiB
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /home/devspice/public_html/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/Test/LoggerInterfaceTest.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

try to make php bin/magento setup:upgrade firstly. 
if it still not successful, you need download and upgrade again Vendor folder of version 2.2.3. Later run all under command to rebuild the component.

rm -rf var/di var/generation var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

Comment: I tried all the things - here is convo.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11114#issuecomment-383096159